# Batch file to read lines from text file which may contain reference of other file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I have some text files which contains some SVN path. These text file will also contain the reference of some other text file which will contain the SVN path and may contain reference to other text file.

Lets see example below:

**text1.txt**

```
http://svnlink1
http://svnlink2
#file#>reference_txt1.txt
#file#>reference_txt2.txt
```

**reference_txt1.txt**

```
http://svnlink3
http://svnlink4
http://svnlink5
http://svnlink6
```

**reference_txt2.txt**

```
http://svnlink7
http://svnlink8
#file#>reference_txt3.txt
```

Here **text1.txt** is my base file which contains 2 SVN links and 2 references of other text files.

All I want is to write the SVN links from all the files whose reference is present in any of the file to some other file say **output.txt**.

Please ask if question is clear or any more details are required.

What I have tried

```
@echo off

cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\
C:

:readLine
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (text1.txt) do call :processline %%a

pause
goto :eof

:processline
set line=%*
IF line contains #file#> (
call:readLine %line%
)
ELSE (
echo %line% >> output.txt
)
goto :eof

:eof
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this. It implements a recursive call of the file reading procedure `process`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=."
SET "ofile=output.txt"
CD /d "%startfolder%"
TYPE NUL>"%ofile%"
CALL :process "text1.txt"
ECHO done.
TYPE "%ofile%"
GOTO :eof

:process
SETLOCAL
FOR /f USEBACKQ %%a IN ("%~1") DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=>" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
        IF NOT "%%c"=="" (
            CALL :process "%%c"
        ) ELSE (
            >>"%ofile%" ECHO(%%a
        )
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
goto:eof
```

Test:

```
>type text1.txt reference_txt?.txt

text1.txt


http://svnlink1
http://svnlink2
#file#>reference_txt1.txt
#file#>reference_txt2.txt

reference_txt1.txt


http://svnlink3
http://svnlink4
http://svnlink5
http://svnlink6

reference_txt2.txt


http://svnlink7
http://svnlink8
#file#>reference_txt3.txt

reference_txt3.txt


http://svnlink9
http://svnlink10
http://svnlink11
http://svnlink12

>script.bat
done.
http://svnlink1
http://svnlink2
http://svnlink3
http://svnlink4
http://svnlink5
http://svnlink6
http://svnlink7
http://svnlink8
http://svnlink9
http://svnlink10
http://svnlink11
http://svnlink12
```

Answer (score 0):

You must quote strings and escape special characters, as `>` which is a special character to redirectt standard output.

```
@echo off

cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\
C:
call :readline text1.txt
goto :eof

:readLine
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=^>" %%a in (%1) do call :processline %%a %%b
pause
goto :eof

:processline
if %2.==. (
    echo %line% >> output.txt
) else (
    if %1=="#file#" call :readLine %2
)
goto :eof
```